# Mobile Emulators not working in visual studio 2015 with update1 Enterprise version

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, emulation

I created a simple UWP application and tried to run it mobile emulators. While building I am get following errors.[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You don't have emulators installed. Maybe your installation is out of date, or HyperV disabled

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35426164/mobile-emulators-not-working-in-visual-studio-2015-with-update1-enterprise-versi

Comment: this solves my problem

Comment: Please Install newer version of SDK to get the problem solved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35426164/mobile-emulators-not-working-in-visual-studio-2015-with-update1-enterprise-versi